# Rally: Load same tasks into multiple stories

Tags: rally

Most of my user stories end up with tasks for create code review, carry out code review, release and deployment etc. Is there a way of setting up these stories somewhere and adding them to a new US as and when required?

Cheers,
Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rally have added a Copy Tasks From... option to the action drop down on the tasks page.

Answer (score 1):

Some customers with this need setup "template" stories pre-populated with the requisite tasks, and leave them un-scheduled, and ranked so they appear at the top of the backlog. Then they use the existing Story Deep Copy Catalog App to make copies of the template stories when creating new stories to write and then pull into sprints.

Answer (score 0):

we created a Ruby script that loads them via the wsapi

-chuck

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be too hard to write an app to do that... Have a template story somewhere with your common tasks that you could then just copy over to a chosen story...